# Using .htaccess "folder" rules to force different content-disposition types?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'm using a origin-pull CDN to distributed files quickly right now. It pulls the files from the origin, including the "type" of the file (download/octect-stream right now) and outputs it to the client.

For that I have the following webserver structure:

```
http://www.server.com/files/code/file.mp4
```

In the directory "files", I have put a .htaccess file to force a download (otherwise it would just start streaming the video file):

```
<Files *.*>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

Now, I would like to allow for both downloadable files and streaming files from the same folder. As you can create "aliases" of a folder using the same .htaccess file, I would like to create the following:

```
http://www.server.com/files/code/file.mp4 -> download
http://www.server.com/streams/code/file.mp4 -> "stream" exactly the same file
```

How can this be done?

Comment: can you update the Apache config or are you forced to use htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ForceType application/octet-stream
> ```

It shouldn't be necessary to override the *correct* `Content-Type` in order to force a download. Setting the appropriate `Content-Disposition` header should be sufficient in all modern browsers.

> you can create "aliases" of a folder using the same .htaccess file

Yes, sort of. Although you wouldn't be able to use the same `.htaccess` in the `/files` directory - if that is what you are implying?

Try the following... remove the `.htaccess` file in the `/files` directory and add the following directives to the `.htaccess` file in the document root (or appropriate subdirectory). These directives may need to go near the top if you have existing directives - the order can be important.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force download all direct requests to the ./files directory
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^files/ - [E=FORCE_DOWNLOAD:1,T=application/octet-stream]

# Internally rewrite requests for ./streams to ./files
RewriteRule ^streams/(.+) files/$1 [L]

# Only set the Content-Disposition header when forcing a download
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=FORCE_DOWNLOAD
```

The above code does still override the `Content-Type` when forcing a download (ie. `T=application/octet-stream` flag on the `RewriteRule`). Although I believe this should be avoided.

The `RewriteCond` directive checking against <del>`THE_REQUEST`</del> `REDIRECT_STATUS` prevents requests for the `./streams` "virtual" directory also being downloaded. It ensures that only "direct" requests for the `./files` directory are downloaded.

Comment: I get an error message: "RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters"

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, the space should be (backslash) escaped in the _CondPattern_. So, `^GET /files/` should be `^GET\ /files/`. I've updated my answer. (Without the space being escaped, the `/files/` bit is seen as the _flags_ argument, which is invalid.)

Comment: That solved the error. But for some reason it is not working as intended. When I target /subdir/files/3/1/filename.mp4 directly, it's streaming. When I target /subdir/streams/3/1/filename.mp4 directly, it's showing a not found error message. My .htaccess file is located in /subdir/ -- any idea why it's not working?

Comment: The above code was intended to work with the URL structure you posted in the question, ie. `/files` and `/streams` both in the document root, not a subdirectory. I've updated my answer and changed the code so it should now work if it is located in either the document root or a subdirectory. (However, this will no longer work if used directly in the server-config, as I had previously stated, but that does not seem to be a requirement here.)

Comment: All worked with this new configuration. Thanks a lot!